# How to set output sound device with selenium in c#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, audio, naudio

I have 30 virtual audio devices and I need to get output from each browser to process audio in real time. To get audio output I am using c# library (naudio) that connects to audio device and gets audio stream. Basically, I need to get sound stream from every browser. How can I set audio device? Or maybe use different way to capture output stream?

I tried using `use-file-for-fake-audio-capture` to get audio stream from file, but it can not be done for real time processing.

I am using seleium to control browser to get to websites which audio I want to process (eg. youtube or facebook). But I have like 30 browsers running at the same time. I think I can use NAudio library to capture stream from a specific application but I didn't find some information about it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but I don't know if this is a good fit for StackOverflow. Typically we need a [repro], but I understand that is difficult, because there isn't a clear way to do this to begin with.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include more information about *why* you want to capture audio in the browser? Selenium might not be the right solution to your problem.